# Excel-Vba script to add multiple rows in cells after number + dot char

Tags: vba, excel, loops, newline

Hopefully you'll be able to assist me with the issue that has been causing headaches for quite a while. I'm too much of a rookie in order to figure this out all by myself, so here it goes:

Is there a way to make VBA go through all the cells in column and add a blank row after each number+dot character

Sample data in a cell:
1. textA2. textB3. textC4. textD5. textE

Desired output after script:
1. textA 
2. textB 
3. textC 
4. textD 
5. textE

Thank you all.

Comment: To do as you ask isn't going to solve your problem.  Will there be more than nine possibilities in a cell?  How does the data wind up in a single cell?  Is there a hidden character that you can use as a delimiter?

Comment: You can use `Split()` to separate the content on the period: combine the first two elements of the array back and then loop over the remaining items adding the required numbers and newline's

Comment: @Tony Large amount of data was exported to multiple spreadsheets and I have no way of accessing original database contents. Number of possibilities ranged from 1 - 50, but most often its within 1-15 range. As far as I know, there's no hidden character that I could use as a delimiter.

Comment: @TimWilliams Thank you for the advice, I'll look into that way of solving the problem. Will let you know of results.

Comment: What do you mean by "blank row"? Does the data remain in the same cell separated by carriage returns, or do you want to split the data to subsequent rows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope this help you:

```
Sub parsingText()
Dim a 'to store the parsed text
Dim t
Dim myAscii As Integer

a = Split(Range("A1"), ".")

For t = 1 To UBound(a)
    myAscii = Asc(Right(a(t), 1)) 'ASCII code of the last char
    If myAscii >= 48 And myAscii <= 57 Then 'the 0-9 numbers are 48-57 ASCII codes
        Cells(t, 2).Value = t & ". " & Left(a(t), Len(a(t)) - Len(t)) 'Take just the text and replace the index counter
    Else
        Cells(t, 2).Value = t & ". " & a(t) 'If the last text has no index (as the 5th)
    End If
Next t
```

End Sub

**Note**: in `Cells(t, 2).Value` I use the column B, you can grab any other. And the text ALWAYS has the same format `number[.][space][text]`

```
RANGE A1: 1. textA2. textB3. textC4. textD5. textE
```

RESULT:

```
Range B1:   1.  textA
Range B2:   2.  textB
Range B3:   3.  textC
Range B4:   4.  textD
Range B5:   5.  textE
```

New Edit: As you ask in the comments

Add an big range for the source data.

```
Sub parsingText()
Dim a 'to store the parsed text
Dim t
Dim myAscii As Integer
Dim rng As Range
Dim R

Set rng = Range("A1:A50")

For Each R In rng
    a = Split(R, ".")
    For t = 1 To UBound(a)
        myAscii = Asc(Right(a(t), 1)) 'ASCII code of the last char
        If t = 1 Then
            If myAscii >= 48 And myAscii <= 57 Then 'the 0-9 numbers are 48-57 ASCII codes
                Cells(R.Row, 2).Value = t & ". " & Left(a(t), Len(a(t)) - Len(t))  'Take just the text and replace the index counter
            Else
                Cells(R.Row, 2).Value = t & ". " & a(t) 'If the last text has no index (as the 5th)
            End If
        Else
            If myAscii >= 48 And myAscii <= 57 Then 'the 0-9 numbers are 48-57 ASCII codes
                Cells(R.Row, 2).Value = Cells(1, 2).Value & vbCrLf & t & ". " & Left(a(t), Len(a(t)) - Len(t + 1)) 'Take just the text and replace the index counter
                'Here the update.
            Else
                Cells(R.Row, 2).Value = Cells(1, 2).Value & vbCrLf & t & ". " & a(t) 'If the last text has no index (as the 5th)
            End If
        End If
    Next t
Next R
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this piece of code, its working!  Is it possible to alter the code so that it covers range - e.g. cells A1-A50 and stores in cells B1-B50? (i presume that editing to cover the range is not difficult, but is it possible to store results again in a single cell instead of sorting in cell range?) - The reason I'm asking is because it would be great if we could still keep single cell contents within 1 cell, but just add blank rows after number[.][space][text] @ElbertV

Comment: Well, I just add some new code to the answer... check it and tell me if it is ok.

Comment: Re-check the answer pls, and see if is what you need.

Comment: It looks much better now, there's just one small detail (its totally fine if this is not fixable, but hopefully it is - just let me know pls): If there are 10 elements (1. textA2. textB3. textC4. textD5. textE6. textF7. textG8. textH9. textI10. textJ), after running the code, 9th element looks like this "9. textI1" - it picks up 1 for some reason. If it does not pick up 1, in scenario with e.g. 15 entries, there's a row with only 1 in it (as 10th element) @ElbertV

Comment: Ready... when comes with a one more digit in the secuence won't let a 1

Comment: @TTZD That's why I asked if there were more than 9 elements.  Do the numbers always start at 1, and are they always sequential?

Comment: Yes with this code it is necessary to be sequential numbers and starting from 1, would be necessary another implementation to take unsorted numbers. If there more than 1000 this code can handle it. Just remember that could be a mess if the string insode the cell is too big. And would be great if you check my answer as the right answer... just saying :)

Comment: @ElbertV your answer solved the issue. Much appreciated.